# Hadoop hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

[image]

I have these kinds of rows in the table 1st is the movie id, 2nd is the movie title, 3rd is the rating given by a person. **There are different movies. NOT all of them are toy story for example**. Its just limited.

The question I have is this:
**Give the name of the movie with the highest ratings**

So for example: if 6 persons give a 1 star rating for a movie the sum is 6. Now to another movie, another 2 persons give ratings, 1 give 5 star and the other one 1 star rating. Then the 2nd one is the highest rated movie.

I need to find this answer working with hadoop hive.

This is what i was able to do until now.
Don't know if I need a function or something else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
select a.movie_name from (
select movie_name, sum(rating) as r, count(*) as cnt
from tableMovieDetail
group by movie_name  ) a
order by a.r , cnt desc
```